# How to change the selected tab programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to change the tab programmatically on swipe. Its implemented successfully but I want to change the tab selection. I used the following code:

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[appDelegate.tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1];
[appDelegate.tabBarController.delegate tabBarController:appDelegate.tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:[[navController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0]];

[appDelegate.tabBarController.tabBar setSelectedItem:[[appDelegate.tabBarController.tabBar items] objectAtIndex:1]];
```

But this gives Exception:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Directly modifying a tab bar managed by a tab bar controller is not allowed.'

Answer (score 1):

Try with: `[self setSelectedIndex:index];`

as self being `UITabBarController` and `index` being index of view controller (from `viewControllers` array) you would like to be selected.

See the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_6)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

if you want to select tab at index 1

```
[appDelegate.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply .. but this doesn't work for me.

Comment: @PanktiPatel did you implemented `shouldSelectViewController:` delegate method of `UITabbarController`

Comment: @PanktiPatel can you show `shouldSelectViewController:` method implementation?

Comment: - (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_0)
{

    
    [appDelegate.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:appDelegate.tabSelectedIndex];
    return YES;
}

Comment: @PanktiPatel why ` [appDelegate.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:appDelegate.tabSelectedIndex];`?

Answer (score 0):

Do not modify a tab bar that is managed by a tab bar controller (an instance of the UITabBarController class). If you do so, the system raises an exception. Modify a managed tab bar, or its items, only through the tab bar controller API.
You can directly modify a tab bar, using methods of this class, if the tab bar is not managed by a tab bar controller.

referenced by [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
[yourTabBar setSelectedItem:[yourTabBar.items objectAtIndex:0]];
```

or

```
[yourTabBar setSelectedIndex:0];
```

Comment: this is what i have implemented but it causes crash.